# Loading Image in P5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

Hey I hope somebody can help me out with this question, well basically I am trying to upload a picture in my canvas through the p5.js library. And as soon as I load my html file I get this:

[image]

I am using brackets, I already tried to set up a web server with wamp server but same thing happened. Here is the code:

```js
//HomePage.js
var rect = [];
var rooms = [];

function preload() {
    for (var i = 0; i <= 1; i++){
        rooms[i] = loadImage("Raeume/" + i + ".jpg"); 
    }

}

function setup() {
    cnv = createCanvas(1000, 600);   
    }

function mousePressed() {
    var r = floor(random(0, rooms.length));
    var b = new Raeume(mouseX, mouseY, rooms[r]);
    rooms.push(b);
}

function draw() {
    background(0);

    for (var i = rooms.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        rooms[i].update();
        rooms[i].display(); 
    }
}
//Raeume.js

function Room (x, y, img) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.img = img;
    
    this.display = function () {
        imageMode(CENTER);
        image(img, this.x, this.y, 100, 100);
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
         
    </head>
        <body>
            <h1>Raum 007</h1>
            <script src="p5/p5.min.js"></script>
            <script src="HomePage.js"></script>
            <script src="Raeume.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

I really hope you guys can help me on this one! Thanks!

Comment: What do you expect to see instead? Have you checked the developer console? Can you link to a CodePen or a JSFiddle? Are those images actually at the URLs you're specifying?

Answer (score 0):

Well, for one, your `rooms` array is holding first two images (assuming those are the right urls), and then you also add a Raeume object onto the end on mousePressed. Thus, when you call update and display on each entity in the array, it might throw some errors. It's very hard to tell what's the real problem since you don't have an example, but I would say the most likely problem is that your images aren't actually named 0.jpg and 1.jpg. If that's not the prob, then you could try running it in firefox, as I think it's more friendly with p5.js.